# Forecasting Holt-Winters (initial values) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

Performing the forecast, I faced the problem.

```
w=ts(mydat$age,frequency = 12,start=c(1946,1))
rainseriesforecasts <- HoltWinters(w, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
rainseriesforecasts
rainseriesforecasts$fitted
```

this code doesn't forecast for initial values, it just outputed this.

```
> rainseriesforecasts$fitted
             xhat    level
Feb 1946 26.66300 26.66300
Mar 1946 25.27676 25.27676
Apr 1946 26.02494 26.02494
```

and this code forecasts next values(for subsequent periods) with 80 and 95 CI

```
w=ts(mydat$age,frequency = 12,start=c(1946,1))
library("forecast")
 m <- stats::HoltWinters(w)

  p = predict(m)
  pp = stats:::predict.HoltWinters(m)
  p
  forecast(m)
  test=forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters(m,h=24)
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Jan 1960       27.30020 26.32517 28.27523 25.80902 28.79139
Feb 1960       25.92822 24.83950 27.01694 24.26316 27.59327
Mar 1960       29.04779 27.85040 30.24518 27.21654 30.87905
```

How to calculate the forecast using Holt-Winters for initial values of the dataset with 80 and 95%CI?
In output I expect next:

```
                 xhat   level   point    80 80  95  95
Feb 1946    26.66300    26.66300    28  28  26  29  29
Mar 1946    25.27676    25.27676    27  30  28  27  25
Apr 1946    26.02494    26.02494    28  29  25  25  25



mydat
structure(list(age = c(26.663, 23.598, 26.931, 24.74, 25.806, 
24.364, 24.477, 23.901, 23.175, 23.227, 21.672, 21.87, 21.439, 
21.089, 23.709, 21.669, 21.752, 20.761, 23.479, 23.824, 23.105, 
23.11, 21.759, 22.073, 21.937, 20.035, 23.59, 21.672, 22.222, 
22.123, 23.95, 23.504, 22.238, 23.142, 21.059, 21.573, 21.548, 
20, 22.424, 20.615, 21.761, 22.874, 24.104, 23.748, 23.262, 22.907, 
21.519, 22.025, 22.604, 20.894, 24.677, 23.673, 25.32, 23.583, 
24.671, 24.454, 24.122, 24.252, 22.084, 22.991, 23.287, 23.049, 
25.076, 24.037, 24.43, 24.667, 26.451, 25.618, 25.014, 25.11, 
22.964, 23.981, 23.798, 22.27, 24.775, 22.646, 23.988, 24.737, 
26.276, 25.816, 25.21, 25.199, 23.162, 24.707, 24.364, 22.644, 
25.565, 24.062, 25.431, 24.635, 27.009, 26.606, 26.268, 26.462, 
25.246, 25.18, 24.657, 23.304, 26.982, 26.199, 27.21, 26.122, 
26.706, 26.878, 26.152, 26.379, 24.712, 25.688, 24.99, 24.239, 
26.721, 23.475, 24.767, 26.219, 28.361, 28.599, 27.914, 27.784, 
25.693, 26.881, 26.217, 24.218, 27.914, 26.975, 28.527, 27.139, 
28.982, 28.169, 28.056, 29.136, 26.291, 26.987, 26.589, 24.848, 
27.543, 26.896, 28.878, 27.39, 28.065, 28.141, 29.048, 28.484, 
26.634, 27.735, 27.132, 24.924, 28.963, 26.589, 27.931, 28.009, 
29.229, 28.759, 28.405, 27.945, 25.912, 26.619, 26.076, 25.286, 
27.66, 25.951, 26.398, 25.565, 28.865, 30, 29.261, 29.012, 26.992, 
27.897)), .Names = "age", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-168L))
```

plot
[image: see the read line]

Comment: If I understand well what you want to do. First adjust a model Holt-Winters (HW) `HW <- HoltWinters(serie)`, and then we could extract their `fitted values` and plot them `plot(serie); lines(HW$fitted [, 1], col = 2)`, now what you want is to get the confidence intervals (80.95) for the `fitted values`. That is for the years 1946, 1947, 1948, ..., 1959?

Comment: Do you want confidence interval of x hat?

Comment: For the 99+% of us who don't know, [Holt-Winters](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/01/29/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting/) is a technique for forecasting timeseries, using additive or multiplicative terms for level, trend and seasonality.

Comment: @Waqas, no i want to get the forecast for initial values. I want get forecast calculated by equation for 1946 year with 80-95% CI. Xhat is not forecast , it is real value! , but check the plot (i edited post,red line is forecast) i want the value of read line (1946-1960 it is forecast line). Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: @varimax, but the output you expect has time starting for 1946 and includes x hat. In my understanding forecasting is done for Feb 1960 and so on. As smci mentioned for most of us  Holt-Winters is a technique for forecasting time series, using additive or multiplicative terms for level, trend and seasonality. What do you mean by you want to get the forecast for initial values?